# How to compare user input to key/value pair in hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am making a really simple quiz program where questions are randomly generated from a hash and the user inputs their answer. I am struggling to compare the user input to a specific question and answer key/value pair. Here are the methods I have so far:

```
  def generate_question
    @questions = {
      "What is the capital of Japan?" => "Tokyo",
      "What is the capital of Portugal?" => "Lisbon"
    }
    keys = questions.keys
    @question = keys[rand(keys.size)]
    puts @question
    response
  end
```

```
  def response
    puts "Please type your answer below"
    @answer = gets.chomp!
    @questions.each do |question, answer|
      if question == @question && answer == @answer
        return "Well done, that's right!"
      else
        return "Not quite right have another go"
      end
    end
  end
```

This only works 50% of the time. For example, if the question 'What is the capital of Japan?' is generated, sometimes 'Tokyo' is correct and sometimes it isn't. Would be really grateful if anyone could help me understand how to compare the user's answer to the right question and answer value in the hash?

Thank you !

Comment: Could the answer be in lowercase?  Try checking if `answer.downcase == @answer.downcase`

Comment: No, didn't work :(

Comment: It always gets the Japan one right but doesn't seem to ever register the Portugal one as correct?

Comment: If you have an `@question` instance variable, instead of iterating, you can just check `@questions[@question]`

Comment: One thing to note about this code is you're using a *lot* of instance variables when you probably don't need to. Instance variables persist for the lifetime of the object meaning they stick around for a long time if you're not careful. Use regular "local" variables (e.g. `questions` instead of `@questions`) unless you specifically need that data to be retained for other method calls.

Comment: thanks for the tip @tadman! :)

Comment: Your question has been answered but readers may wish to suggest how you might restructure your code. To do that, however, a clarification of the question is needed. If the answer to a question is incorrect, "Not quite right have another go" is displayed. What do you expect the user to do in that case? Make further attempts to answer the same question until the correct answer is given? Incidentally, in future consider waiting longer (say > 2 hours) before selecting an answer, so as to not discourage other answers. There's no rush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occuring because you are iterating through the hash.  To fix this, use the `@question` instance variable.

```
def response
    puts "Please type your answer below"
    @answer = gets.chomp!
    correct_answer = @questions[@question]

    if correct_answer == @answer
        return "Well done, that's right!"
    else
        return "Not quite right have another go"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue it this part

```
@questions.each do |question, answer|
  if question == @question && answer == @answer
    return "Well done, that's right!"
  else
    return "Not quite right have another go"
  end
end
```

If the first question is not the question that was asked it will immediately return that you are wrong without looking at the next question because the return returns from the `method` not from the block.

Even if it returned from the block though it would say you were wrong and then say you were right (if you answered the second question correctly).

To solve this you can change it to

```
def response
  puts "Please type your answer below"
  @answer = gets.chomp!
  if @questions[@question].to_s.downcase == @answer.downcase
     "Well done, that's right!"
  else 
     "Not quite right have another go"
  end 
end
```

Now we are looking up the answer based on the question and making the answer case insensitive